# PHP + Dropbox API V2 - show thumbnail

Tags: php, image, output, thumbnails, dropbox-api

I'm trying to display five images from my Dropbox account through PHP.
Listing them works perfectly using https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/list_folder and `curl`. 
The json output, I turn into a PHP array, which tells me what files I need.
Subsequently, I call the images using https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/get_thumbnail:

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/get_thumbnail");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "cacert.pem");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,     '{"path":"/images/1234.jpg","format":{".tag":"jpeg"},"size":{".tag":"w1024h768"}');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Authorization: Bearer SECRET_CODE";
$headers[] = "Content-Type: application/json";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close ($ch);

?>
```

According to documentation this returns some metadata and the main body is the image. Now, what I'm struggling with is how to display the image, as if you were directly accessing the image through the URL (so I can out it in an `<img src="">`).
I recon I need `header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');` but I have no other clue on how to continue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Best,
Knal

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-support/PHP-Show-thumbnail/m-p/239811#M13349 ]

Answer (score 0):

Get thumbnail request are via the header rather than a Post request. try

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/get_thumbnail");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "cacert.pem");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Authorization: Bearer SECRET_CODE";
$headers[] = "Dropbox-API-Arg: {"path":"/images/1234.jpg","format":{".tag":"jpeg"},"size":{".tag":"w1024h768"}";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close ($ch);
```